# Any advice on how to tune parameters to download urls faster with less errors? (trio + asks)

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, python-trio

I'am writing simple program that downloads list of urls.

### prepare list of urls

```
!curl -LO https://github.com/mozilla/cipherscan/raw/master/top1m/top-1m.csv
!head -5 top-1m.csv    
1,google.com
2,facebook.com
3,youtube.com
4,yahoo.com
5,baidu.com



alexa_1m = []
with open('top-1m.csv') as csv:
    lines = csv.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        index, url = line.split(',')
        alexa_1m.append(url)


print(len(alexa_1m))
print(alexa_1m[:6])
1000000
['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'youtube.com', 'yahoo.com', 'baidu.com', 'wikipedia.org']
```

### main code

```
import asks
import trio
import time

async def fetch(s, url):
    try:
        response = await s.get('http://' + url, timeout=15, connection_timeout=15)
        html_str = response.text
        results[url] = len(html_str) # save only html length for simplicity
    except BaseException as e:
        errors [url] = type(e).__name__

async def main(urls):
    s = asks.Session(connections=20)
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        for url in urls:
            nursery.start_soon(fetch, s, url)

for n_urls in [10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 500, 600, 700, 800, 1000, 2000]:
    urls = alexa_1m[:n_urls]

    results = dict()
    errors  = dict()

    start_time = time.time()
    trio.run(main, urls)
    total_time = time.time() - start_time

    assert len(results) + len(errors) == len(urls)

    print(f'time {total_time:>8.4f} | RPS {(n_urls / total_time):>8.4f} | URLS {len(urls):>6} | RESULTS {len(results):>6} | ERRORS {len(errors):>6}')
```

output for `connections=10`

```
time  16.8685 | RPS   0.5928 | URLS     10 | RESULTS      9 | ERRORS      1
time  10.9119 | RPS   2.2911 | URLS     25 | RESULTS     25 | ERRORS      0
time  17.8106 | RPS   2.8073 | URLS     50 | RESULTS     49 | ERRORS      1
time  19.0452 | RPS   3.9380 | URLS     75 | RESULTS     71 | ERRORS      4
time  19.1133 | RPS   5.2320 | URLS    100 | RESULTS     91 | ERRORS      9
time  18.1323 | RPS   8.2725 | URLS    150 | RESULTS    140 | ERRORS     10
time  27.2238 | RPS   7.3465 | URLS    200 | RESULTS    190 | ERRORS     10
time  33.8300 | RPS   7.3899 | URLS    250 | RESULTS    240 | ERRORS     10
time  40.0035 | RPS   7.4994 | URLS    300 | RESULTS    287 | ERRORS     13
time  67.6925 | RPS   7.3863 | URLS    500 | RESULTS    475 | ERRORS     25
time  78.3422 | RPS   7.6587 | URLS    600 | RESULTS    568 | ERRORS     32
time  98.5214 | RPS   7.1051 | URLS    700 | RESULTS    658 | ERRORS     42
time 118.0234 | RPS   6.7783 | URLS    800 | RESULTS    747 | ERRORS     53
time 154.7543 | RPS   6.4619 | URLS   1000 | RESULTS    928 | ERRORS     72
time 356.5015 | RPS   5.6101 | URLS   2000 | RESULTS   1813 | ERRORS    187
time 571.1392 | RPS   5.2527 | URLS   3000 | RESULTS   2699 | ERRORS    301
```

output for `connections=20`

```
time   3.1848 | RPS   3.1399 | URLS     10 | RESULTS     10 | ERRORS      0
time  22.6056 | RPS   1.1059 | URLS     25 | RESULTS     24 | ERRORS      1
time  15.0470 | RPS   3.3229 | URLS     50 | RESULTS     49 | ERRORS      1
time  16.8384 | RPS   4.4541 | URLS     75 | RESULTS     72 | ERRORS      3
time  18.2071 | RPS   5.4924 | URLS    100 | RESULTS     90 | ERRORS     10
time  20.6861 | RPS   7.2512 | URLS    150 | RESULTS    140 | ERRORS     10
time  21.7591 | RPS   9.1915 | URLS    200 | RESULTS    190 | ERRORS     10
time  25.2696 | RPS   9.8933 | URLS    250 | RESULTS    239 | ERRORS     11
time  31.1732 | RPS   9.6237 | URLS    300 | RESULTS    285 | ERRORS     15
time  51.9217 | RPS   9.6299 | URLS    500 | RESULTS    471 | ERRORS     29
time  53.7469 | RPS  11.1634 | URLS    600 | RESULTS    567 | ERRORS     33
time  58.8306 | RPS  11.8986 | URLS    700 | RESULTS    657 | ERRORS     43
time  65.4025 | RPS  12.2320 | URLS    800 | RESULTS    744 | ERRORS     56
time  96.4105 | RPS  10.3723 | URLS   1000 | RESULTS    926 | ERRORS     74
time 225.2461 | RPS   8.8792 | URLS   2000 | RESULTS   1813 | ERRORS    187
```

output for `connections=100`

```
time   4.1067 | RPS   2.4350 | URLS     10 | RESULTS     10 | ERRORS      0
time  16.7758 | RPS   1.4902 | URLS     25 | RESULTS     24 | ERRORS      1
time  17.3520 | RPS   2.8815 | URLS     50 | RESULTS     47 | ERRORS      3
time  16.0240 | RPS   4.6805 | URLS     75 | RESULTS     71 | ERRORS      4
time  16.0592 | RPS   6.2270 | URLS    100 | RESULTS     90 | ERRORS     10
time  19.6826 | RPS   7.6209 | URLS    150 | RESULTS    138 | ERRORS     12
time  20.9570 | RPS   9.5433 | URLS    200 | RESULTS    189 | ERRORS     11
time  22.2123 | RPS  11.2550 | URLS    250 | RESULTS    239 | ERRORS     11
time  28.9885 | RPS  10.3489 | URLS    300 | RESULTS    285 | ERRORS     15
time  45.7558 | RPS  10.9276 | URLS    500 | RESULTS    468 | ERRORS     32
time  40.8652 | RPS  14.6824 | URLS    600 | RESULTS    565 | ERRORS     35
time  48.3942 | RPS  14.4645 | URLS    700 | RESULTS    656 | ERRORS     44
time  56.0546 | RPS  14.2718 | URLS    800 | RESULTS    744 | ERRORS     56
time  67.9813 | RPS  14.7099 | URLS   1000 | RESULTS    924 | ERRORS     76
time 205.3066 | RPS   9.7415 | URLS   2000 | RESULTS   1727 | ERRORS    273
time 275.1011 | RPS  10.9051 | URLS   3000 | RESULTS   2572 | ERRORS    428
```

output for `connections=1000`

```
time   2.7290 | RPS   3.6643 | URLS     10 | RESULTS     10 | ERRORS      0
time  15.4174 | RPS   1.6215 | URLS     25 | RESULTS     24 | ERRORS      1
time  15.4496 | RPS   3.2363 | URLS     50 | RESULTS     48 | ERRORS      2
time  16.3329 | RPS   4.5920 | URLS     75 | RESULTS     70 | ERRORS      5
time  15.7269 | RPS   6.3585 | URLS    100 | RESULTS     90 | ERRORS     10
time  16.8205 | RPS   8.9177 | URLS    150 | RESULTS    139 | ERRORS     11
time  15.9112 | RPS  12.5697 | URLS    200 | RESULTS    190 | ERRORS     10
time  16.2899 | RPS  15.3469 | URLS    250 | RESULTS    240 | ERRORS     10
time  16.4773 | RPS  18.2069 | URLS    300 | RESULTS    286 | ERRORS     14
time  35.9516 | RPS  13.9076 | URLS    500 | RESULTS    133 | ERRORS    367
time  21.9307 | RPS  27.3589 | URLS    600 | RESULTS    226 | ERRORS    374
time  25.0500 | RPS  27.9441 | URLS    700 | RESULTS    396 | ERRORS    304
time  51.7007 | RPS  15.4737 | URLS    800 | RESULTS     93 | ERRORS    707
time  54.0819 | RPS  18.4905 | URLS   1000 | RESULTS     98 | ERRORS    902
time 171.3959 | RPS  11.6689 | URLS   2000 | RESULTS    206 | ERRORS   1794
```

output for `connections=10000`

```
time  11.5818 | RPS   0.8634 | URLS     10 | RESULTS     10 | ERRORS      0
time   9.3749 | RPS   2.6667 | URLS     25 | RESULTS     25 | ERRORS      0
time  15.1868 | RPS   3.2923 | URLS     50 | RESULTS     49 | ERRORS      1
time  15.1500 | RPS   4.9505 | URLS     75 | RESULTS     72 | ERRORS      3
time  15.7089 | RPS   6.3658 | URLS    100 | RESULTS     91 | ERRORS      9
time  19.6824 | RPS   7.6210 | URLS    150 | RESULTS    139 | ERRORS     11
time  16.5324 | RPS  12.0975 | URLS    200 | RESULTS    190 | ERRORS     10
time  19.9391 | RPS  12.5382 | URLS    250 | RESULTS    238 | ERRORS     12
time  20.4344 | RPS  14.6811 | URLS    300 | RESULTS    284 | ERRORS     16
time  32.1311 | RPS  15.5612 | URLS    500 | RESULTS    376 | ERRORS    124
time  26.8989 | RPS  22.3057 | URLS    600 | RESULTS    363 | ERRORS    237
time  41.2159 | RPS  16.9837 | URLS    700 | RESULTS    176 | ERRORS    524
time  48.1362 | RPS  16.6195 | URLS    800 | RESULTS     83 | ERRORS    717
time  55.6773 | RPS  17.9606 | URLS   1000 | RESULTS    114 | ERRORS    886
time 130.0663 | RPS  15.3768 | URLS   2000 | RESULTS    244 | ERRORS   1756
```

When there are many tasks and many connections I get most of requests failed with `RequestTimeout` and `gaierror`:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.islice(errors.items(), 100))
```

output

```
[
('ggpht.com', 'gaierror'),
('ilivid.com', 'gaierror'),
('lpmxbox600.com', 'gaierror'),
('matlabgah.com', 'gaierror'),
('palxxx.com', 'gaierror'),
('ytimg.com', 'gaierror'),
('paipai.com', 'gaierror'),
('hotspotshield.com', 'OSError'),
('icmwebserv.com', 'gaierror'),
('bgr.com', 'BadHttpResponse'),
('directrev.com', 'gaierror'),
('workercn.cn', 'gaierror'),
('axisbank.co.in', 'gaierror'),
('intentmedia.net', 'gaierror'),
('reliancebroadband.co.in', 'RequestTimeout'),
('v9.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('tebyan.net', 'RequestTimeout'),
('asriran.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('akairan.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('tuolar.com', 'gaierror'),
('thomann.de', 'RequestTimeout'),
('unian.net', 'BadHttpResponse'),
('rr.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('multitran.ru', 'BadHttpResponse'),
('chexun.com', 'OSError'),
('geocities.jp', 'gaierror'),
('plaintube.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('rei.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('ldblog.jp', 'gaierror'),
('dfiles.ru', 'SSLError'),
('shahrekhabar.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('asos.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('yjc.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('mihanblog.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('sportsdirect.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('mmgp.ru', 'RequestTimeout'),
('cloob.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('alluc.to', 'OSError'),
('postimg.org', 'gaierror'),
('sockshare.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('khabarpu.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('mashreghnews.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('chinabroadcast.cn', 'RequestTimeout'),
('linksynergy.com', 'gaierror'),
('akamaihd.net', 'gaierror'),
('bmi.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('cartfill.in', 'gaierror'),
('cocolog-nifty.com', 'gaierror'),
('extra.com.br', 'RequestTimeout'),
('installerapplicationusa.com', 'gaierror'),
('chinanews.com', 'BadHttpResponse'),
('taobaocdn.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('sweetim.com', 'gaierror'),
('timesjobs.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('persianblog.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('haivl.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('shaparak.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('rozblog.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('statscrop.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('pgmediaserve.com', 'gaierror'),
('xhamster.com/user/video', 'BadHttpResponse'),
('mysearchresults.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('downloadquick.net', 'gaierror'),
('alimama.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('bodybuilding.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('sergey-mavrodi.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('societe.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('series.ly', 'RequestTimeout'),
('daum.net', 'RequestTimeout'),
('myfreshnet.com', 'gaierror'),
('archive.today', 'RequestTimeout'),
('sweet-page.com', 'SSLError'),
('shop.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('nasdaq.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('tvrain.ru', 'BadHttpResponse'),
('tsetmc.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('delta-homes.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('seemorgh.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('inetglobal.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('medu.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('readmanga.eu', 'RequestTimeout'),
('goo.ne.jp', 'RequestTimeout'),
('indiegogo.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('lpcloudbox328.com', 'gaierror'),
('secureinternetbank.com', 'gaierror'),
('picofile.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('styletv.com.cn', 'RequestTimeout'),
('tv.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('extratorrent.cc', 'RequestTimeout'),
('a8.net', 'RequestTimeout'),
('livedoor.biz', 'gaierror'),
('adk2.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('cmbchina.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('gruposantander.es', 'gaierror'),
('beamtele.com', 'gaierror'),
('ppstream.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('icicibank.co.in', 'RequestTimeout'),
('bartarinha.ir', 'RequestTimeout'),
('theblaze.com', 'RequestTimeout'),
('americanas.com.br', 'RequestTimeout')
]
```

**Any advice on how to tune this parameters:

in order to download urls faster with less errors?**

- number of tasks/urls for `trio.run(main, urls)` (is it better to break it into chunks?)
- number of connections (is this limited to my hardware?  is `1000` too big? `10000`?)
- `timeout` and `connection_timeout`

Answer (score 1):

> number of tasks/urls for `trio.run(main, urls)` (is it better to break it into chunks?)

I don't think there's any need to break it into chunks... usually it's simplest to just have a single `trio.run` at the beginning of your program to switch into "trio mode", and then stay in trio mode from then on.

> number of connections (is this limited to my hardware? is 1000 too big? 10000?)

This is impossible to predict -- it's going to depend on your network connection and all kinds of things. I think the best you can do is what you're already doing: try some different values and see.

> timeout and connection_timeout

Again, you probably want to tune these empirically. Too long, and you waste ages waiting for connections that are never going to respond. Too short, and you cut off connections that were working.

Some amount of timeout and DNS lookup errors are inevitable when you're trying to saturate your network like this. I think the best approach is just to add some retry logic: if the first attempt errors out, then try again up to three times, or something like that.

The [`tenacity`](https://github.com/jd/tenacity) library is good for this. Here's an example of using tenacity and trio together in a real project: https://github.com/pypa/linehaul/blob/89ed128deb714827f732d0404d4d664ee4fc1634/linehaul/server.py